# How to read from a text file and populate a combo box in flash AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Suppose a text file contains the following data each separated by a line

Apple

Mango

Orange

Banana

Papaya

How do I read the text file in flash and then display it in a combo box in flash ?

Comment: This sounds more like one of those can you do my work for me questions.

Comment: Well I tried looking everywhere. I was able to make a combobox. I was able to load a txt file. But I was not able to combine both of them. Is there a place to learn things like that in detail?

Answer (score 0):

use URLLoader to load txt file , than get String(data) , parse it ( string.split("\n") )  and using for() create list and add to combo box.